# Update a table using two other tables like Join condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a three tables as below

TABLE H

```
H_ID   FLG
1    -
2    -
3    -
4    HERE
5    NO
```

TABLE C

```
C_ID  STS
1      1345
2      1345
3      1346
4      1346
5      1345
6      1348
7      1223
```

TABLE S

```
STS_ID    VALUE
1345       START
1346       END
1348       WILD
1223       MID
1111       ON-GOING
2345       THERE
```

I want to update `table H` with data from `value` Column in `table S`

I wrote query as below

```
UPDATE table H h
SET FLG = (SELECT s.VALUE 
           FROM table C c 
             JOIN table S s 
               ON s.STS_ID = c.C_ID      
           WHERE c.C_ID = h.H_ID)     
WHERE h.H_ID IN (1,2,3);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please explain what "wont work" means.  Are you getting an error?  Is it not doing what you want?

Comment: Make sure the subquery never returns more than one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the join on `S` and `C` in the subquery uses the wrong columns:

```
UPDATE table H h
SET FLG = (SELECT s.VALUE
           FROM table C c JOIN
                table S s
                ON s.STS_ID = c.STS
           WHERE c.C_ID = h.H_ID
          )
WHERE h.H_ID IN (1, 2, 3);
```